# Adding multiple children at multiple levels with a loop and "clean" code

Tags: c#, loops, children

I have a C# Class that can contain multiple children at multiple levels.

Adding children manually would look something like this:

```
CustomClass MyClass = new CustomClass(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
//Level 1
MyClass.Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
//Level 2
MyClass.Children[0].Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
//Level 3
MyClass.Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
```

How would I do this with a clean loop instead? Doing it like this, doesn’t feel “right”:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   //Level 1
   if (i == 0)
        MyClass.Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
   //Level 2
   if (i == 1)
        MyClass.Children[0].Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
   //Level 3
   if (i == 2)
        MyClass.Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());

    // and so on up to 50 levels in this case ...
}
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE: At every level I need to check if the value already exists, if it doesn't, I add it.**

Thank you for listening!

I'm a beginner so please be gentle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the value". Can you put an example of the comparison you need to do at each level?

Comment: do you need to check if the value exists anywhere, or at the current level? @Matt Eilen's answer still works for either scenario, you just need to add a check before you do the add and return if the check returns true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it recursively:

```
void FillChildren(CustomClass lastChild, int levels)
{
    if(levels > 0)
    {
        CustomClass child = new CustomClass(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());
        FillChildren(child, levels-1);
        lastChild.Children.Add(“something”, child);
    }
}
```

Which you would call like so:

```
CustomClass MyClass = new CustomClass(“something”, new List<CustomClass>());

FillChildren(MyClass, 50);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, don't really know if it can help me tough. Updated the question a bit, missed an important part, sorry about that! :(

Comment: I'll post a more specific question about this and then I'll post the url here. The question should have been more detailed from the start, sry again!

Comment: Here the question in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474922/adding-multiple-unique-children-at-multiple-levels-with-one-or-more-loops-and-cl ty!